# Stacking odd number of tabs - jquery/css

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I've got 5 tabs that, on mobile, I'd like to arrange in a stack with the odd tab out at the top instead of the bottom. Currently I have them set to 50% the width of the container and floated left, but of course they fill up the top first.

```
<div class="tab-row">
  <button class="tab active">A</button>
  <button class="tab">B</button>
  <button class="tab">C</button>
  <button class="tab">D</button>
  <button class="tab">E</button>
</div>
```

And here's the code handling tab selection at the moment:

```
$(".tab").click(function() {


  // All versions
  $(".tab").removeClass("active");
  $(".tab").show();
  $(".clone").remove();

  // mobile version does clone thing rather than moving $(this) in order to preserve original order of inactive tabs

  if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1100px)").matches) {
     $(this).clone().addClass("clone active").insertAfter(".tab-row button:last-of-type");
     $(this).hide();
  }
  // full width
  else { $(this).addClass("active"); }

  // code to load the tab content elided

  });
```

(There's some separate code that puts Tab A at the bottom when it loads on mobile.)

When working on this earlier, I was IIRC able to get some mileage by setting a clear:, but the whole clone js messes that up so it didn't always work the way I wanted. I don't know if I was just going about it wrong, or if it's unfeasible to go that route?

I feel like the answer must be obvious but I can't figure it out... Thanks in advance!

Helpful illustration located at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttNwW.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` along with `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`

```js
$(".tab").click(function() {


  // All versions
  $(".tab").removeClass("active");
  $(".tab").show();
  $(".clone").remove();

  // mobile version does clone thing rather than moving $(this) in order to preserve original order of inactive tabs

  if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1100px)").matches) {
     $(this).clone().addClass("clone active").insertAfter(".tab-row button:last-of-type");
     $(this).hide();
  }
  // full width
  else { $(this).addClass("active"); }

  // code to load the tab content elided

  });
```

```css
.tab-row{
    max-width:100px;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.tab{
  width:35px;
  margin:5px;
  align-self:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-row">
  <button class="tab active">A</button>
  <button class="tab">B</button>
  <button class="tab">C</button>
  <button class="tab">D</button>
  <button class="tab">E</button>
</div>
```

You can also test it here.. https://jsfiddle.net/kt39Lp71/1/

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to run it by other people (to make sure they're all right having Tab A down at the bottom right when it's not being used, and Tab E at the top) but this is helpful.

Comment: Sure. If this is helpful, can you please accept the solution so that it can help others?